# Allow html in taxonomy names in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, strip, custom-taxonomy

**Situation:**
I'm working on a WordPress website with a custom taxonomy with a lot of terms. The name of some terms are too long for mobile screen sizes, so the name needs to break when it doesn't fit the screen. I know i can use `hyphens: auto` in css to break words, but this isn't the solution because there's no control about the location of the break and beside that, it's not steady in every browser.

**Goal:**
Instead of the css solution i want to use the `&shy;` html symbol. This way i've full control where the name will break. Wordpress allows `&shy;` on post and page titles, but not on category or taxonomy names. It strips the html when saving the taxonomy. The goal is to allow the `&shy;` symbol in taxonomy names.

---

I've been searching for hours now and can't find a solution. The only thing i've found is the filter '[wp_filter_kses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_kses/)' which sanitize the content. Maybe this filter needs to be removed, so the input at the taxonomy name doesn't get sanitized while saving, but i've no clue how to manage this.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution! [This](https://medium.com/@clarklab/add-a-line-break-in-a-wordpress-title-b3aeff346037) article showed me another way to fix it. I'm using the | character in the name of the taxonomy. In the front-end, the character will be replaced with a `&shy;` symbol:

```
<?php echo str_replace('|', '&shy;', $taxonomy_name); ?>
```